# How to order results for Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook

I've been playing around the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) for a while now. 
I'm trying to get the list of friends using `https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends`.

While it's working fine, the results are ordered by Id. Is there a way to get them ordered by name, or do I have to reorder them manually via my application layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of ordering Graph API results, but you can order FQL results. Something like:

```
SELECT name, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = $current_user_id) ORDER BY name
```